# Как вывести кастомные материалы плюс ещё с учётом своей таксономии (wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал свой тип материалов в wordpresse. Во-первых, им можно придавать три формата: стандартный, видео и изображение. Во-вторых, ещё задавать периоды времени к которым относятся.

Нужно чтобы записи сортировались, в первую очередь, по этим периодам. А внутри каждого периода выводились группами в зависимости от формата: видео, изображение и стандартный.

Пока что у меня вот так:

```
$args = array(
               'post_type' => 'otzivi',
               'publish' => true,
               'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
           );

        query_posts($args);

   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-7">

      <h1><? the_title(); ?></h1>
      <?php if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs(); ?>
      <? the_content(); ?>

      <? include 'share.php'; ?>
    </div>
  <? endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Выводится соответственно просто списком (плюс, как я понял лучше использовать get_posts(); )

В functions.php создаю таксономию для периода времени:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_taxonomies', 0 );


function create_book_taxonomies(){

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Года', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Год', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Поиск года' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'Все года' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Редактировать год' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Обновить год' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Добавить год' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'Новый год' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Период времени' ),
);


register_taxonomy('tax_otzivi', array('otzivi'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,

));
```

}

Добавляю тип формата записи:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'image', 'video' ) );
```

И в коде, где регистрирую этот материла добавляю поддержку 'post-formats'

Comment: Покажите код, которым вы присваиваете формат и период времени вашим отзывам.

Comment: @KAGGDesign добавил к описанию вопроса